# Reference for: Every local field can be realized as the completion of a global field

Tags: nt.number-theory, local-fields, global-fields

It is well known that every local field (i.e. nondiscrete topological field locally compact with respect to the topology) is the completion of some global field.  I know the argument, a nice exposition is

http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/248APage/handouts/localglobal.pdf

My question is, does anyone know a *published* reference for this fact?

Comment: The only case that isn't trivial is finite extensions of Q_p, and then it's just immediate from Krasner's Lemma isn't it? Extension is separable so simple, take min poly, adjust so that coefficients are in Q, and done.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly as Lorenz proves the statement in the textbook that I quoted below.

Comment: Might I ask (well, I will): why do you need a *published* source for this result?

Comment: @KConrad: I am writing a book on automorphic representations with H. Hahn and I want to state this with a reference but not prove it.

Comment: A two line proof as in wrigley's answer would surely be more useful to your readers than a reference. Readers who don't know Krasner's lemma can look it up in the Wikipedia.

Comment: I agree with zeno that you should take a couple of lines and sketch the proof in your book, you can then refer the reader to Lorenz's book for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F. Lorenz: *[Algebra. Volume II: Fields with Structure, Algebras and Advanced Topics](http://www.springer.com/jp/book/9780387724874)*, Theorem 2 p. 78.